# Parameters of a current sense amplifier

Tags: amplifier, gain-bandwidth-product

I am trying to select a current sense amplifier for my design. My design parameters are :-

Vrail:- 9V to 21V
ILoad :- 20A(max)

When I look on digikey,

http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/linear-amplifiers-instrumentation-op-amps-buffer-amps/2556125

I am confused with 2 parameters:-

1. Gain bandwidth product
2. -3db Bandwidth

Can someone explain these parameters? What is their significance in selecting right sense amplifier?

Comment: How high frequency do you need to measure to? How much output voltage do you need to produce at maximum current? The product of these two answers are your gain-bandwidth product. -3dB bandwidth of the OPamp should be higher than the maximum frequency you need to measure.

Comment: Here is one of the many Internet resources that provide the answers to your questions regarding op amp bandwidth: [Operational Amplifier Basics](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_1.html).

Comment: There are also dedicated current sense amplifiers. You might consider using one of those, depending on details of your application.

Comment: What is the current that you are trying to measure? An op-amp may not be the best solution. Try googling "current-sense amplifier". (oops, mkeith beat me by a minute - I need to type faster).